# Understanding Salesforce Developer Docs

Tags: documentation

Where can I find resources that explain the layout of Salesforce docs. Like what the different detail subtitles are and mean. For example, what does **properties** mean and what is the full list of values?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the Object Reference for Salesforce. On the left, under Pages, you will see all the different sections of the Object Reference. The different subheadings are explained on earlier pages.

The properties are explained under *API Field Properties* here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/access_for_fields.htm

If you prefer, the whole thing is available as a PDF: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/244/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/object_reference.pdf